# Can a Castle DynamicProxy interceptor change argument values?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

We're using DynamicProxy in a project. I've created an interceptor for a few methods.

I know that it's possible to get the method arguments inside of a `Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor` object.

Can an interceptor change the value of the arguments passed to a method, before calling `invocation.Proceed()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - yes, it can.

In this case, one can use Reflection on the `IInvocation.Method` property to get the method parameters; the method arguments are attached directly to the invocation. Although the arguments property is a readonly value (no public setter) it's of type `object[]` - so its properties are writable.

Thus, an interceptor can change argument values by writing to the `arguments` object, using the correct index corresponding to the method parameter position.